# Во время копирования с помощью hotkey('Ctrl', 'c') программа пытается переключить язык

Tags: python, pyautogui

Я использую в своем коде следующую строку для копирования выделенного текста

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'с')
```

Проблема заключается в том, что если запустить программу под русской раскладкой например, то она пытается нажимать shift + alt, а если запускать под английской, то все отлично работает. Причем если запустить под русской и в переключить язык во время работы программы, то все так же будет нажимать shift + alt. Пытался насильно переключить раскладку на английскую в самом начале выполнения кода, но это никакого эффекта не дало. Что можно с этим делать?